# Weblogic EJB can not commit XA transaction when use Foreign JNDI to call remote EJB

Tags: transactions, ejb, weblogic, xa

Currently I am using Weblogic 12.1.2 DEV edition for EJB development. And I need to call a remote EJB (another Weblogic server). So I configured a Foreign JNDI Provider pointed to this remote EJB. Everything is good until the my local EJB bean try to commit transaction, I got below exception:

```
<Dec 27, 2013 10:23:51 AM CST> <Error> <EJB> <BEA-010026> <Exception occurred during commit of transaction Name=[EJB test.bean.HelloBean.hello()],Xid=BEA1-00022F80B0CCE5A4E067(808603218),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=javax.transaction.SystemException: Commit can be issued only when there are no requests awaiting responses. Currently there is one such request],numRepliesOwedMe=1,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=21,seconds left=30,SCInfo[domain1+AdminServer]=(state=rolledback),properties=({weblogic.transaction.name=[EJB test.bean.HelloBean.hello()]}),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=AdminServer+10.136.0.15:7001+domain1+t3+, XAResources={dev/sqlserver_domain1, WSATGatewayRM_AdminServer_domain1, local/sqlserver_domain1},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=AdminServer+10.136.0.15:7001+domain1+t3+): weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Commit can be issued only when there are no requests awaiting responses. Currently there is one such request
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.throwRollbackException(TransactionImpl.java:1878)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:359)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.commit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:250)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.postInvoke1(BaseRemoteObject.java:374)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessRemoteObject.postInvoke1(StatelessRemoteObject.java:20)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseRemoteObject.java:226)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:47)
    at test.bean.HelloBean_gbyfgg_HelloImpl.hello(Unknown Source)
    at test.bean.HelloBean_gbyfgg_HelloImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:693)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:519)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:515)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: Commit can be issued only when there are no requests awaiting responses. Currently there is one such request
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.abort(TransactionImpl.java:1151)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.enforceCheckedTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:1809)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.checkIfCommitPossible(TransactionImpl.java:1787)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalCommit(ServerTransactionImpl.java:275)
    ... 16 more
.>
```

Before I add this remote EJB call, the app is calling to two sql server instances with weblogic provided no-xa JDBC driver. However they Supports Global Transactions by enable Emulate Two-Phase Commit. The app went well while commit or rollback. After added this remote EJB call into process, XA transaction can not commit any more. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You have three options and your should decide which one is best depending on your non-functional requirements (e.g. security etc):

- Enable global domain trust between all domains - basically you set the domain credential on all domains to the same value
- Enable cross-domain security - you create users on both sides, add them to the cross-domain-connectors group, define cross-domain credential mapping and enable the cross-domain security in your domain configuration
- Change the domain interoperability mode to performance on all domains - this will cause the transaction coordinators to use an anonymous login

I have tried the latter and they both worked. You can find more details if you google the keywords from above - there is some rudimentary weblogic documentation on all of the cases above.

You might also want to enable the transactions logging using the console while you are trying to get it to work. It prints a lot of information, some of which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Does the remote ejb call complete successfully or does it throw an exception/ This remote ejb call is executed on behalf of the same transaction.

Comment: remote ejb call complete successfully, but it seemed not in the same transaction. I wander why, or I miss something.

Comment: what operation is the remote ejb call executing, especially in terms of database transactions? Is it possible that the ejb call tries to commit. Be aware that you are only using emulated xa, which does not guarantee rollback of the transaction.

Comment: The remote ejb call is to create a record in DB. But after this exception thrown, the record is still in DB. That is why i believe remote ejb call is not in the same transaction. Another thing is, I don't enable cross domain security. I just use global trust to do this. Am I doing right?

Comment: This means the remote ejb call is committing, which is a violation of the emulated 2PC protocol.

Comment: That is strange thing. Anyway, I finally got this working. Here are the steps:
    1. Enabled weblogic Cross Domain Security.
    2. Change Security Interoperability Mode to compatilibity
    3. Add Credential to default user "weblogic"
    4. Running the MS DTC Service refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335.aspx

Now I am using MS provided XA JDBC driver to get distribution transaction working.